# URL and query string in Grails UrlMappings

Tags: grails, groovy, query-string, url-mapping, request.querystring

After searching for a while, I'm still not able to do the following using Grails. I want match a variable with some part of URL plus the query string.

I have the following rule in UrlMappings:

```
"/myservice/$url**?"{
    controller = "mycontroller"
    action = "myaction"
}
```

With this, I'm able to grab the portion of the URL that want via `params.url`, except the query string.

In other words, I want to grab everything that comes after `/myservice/` in a variable.

I know I can get the query string with `request.queryString`, but I would prefer the way I'm suggesting. Maybe this is not even possible...

Comment: try "/myservice/$url**"

Comment: @Raphael doesn't help...

Comment: Did you already try "/controller/some${action}/"?

Comment: @ricardogobbo Yes, but doesn't help also... Thanks anyway!